# update GUI for SelectedeRow values of wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light, inotifypropertychanged

I have a wpf (.Net 4.5) datagrid.  I am using the MVVM pattern for my application with the MVVM-Light framework.

I have a datagrid that is bound to an observable collection of "Tracking" objects called TrackingCollection.  The datagrid selectedItem is bound to a "SelectedTracking" property in the viewModel.

```
<DataGrid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" MinHeight="300"          
          ItemsSource="{Binding TrackingCollection}"    
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False"
          SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTracking, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
           RowDetailsTemplate="{StaticResource FTC_TrackingFullDetailTemplate}">
</DataGrid>
```

I have a comboBox in one column that is bound to an "idAction" property of the SelectedTracking object.  When the user changes the selection of this comboBox, I want to assign the values of two other combo boxes in two other columns of the datagrid.  These other columns are not bound to properties of the view model, rather they are bound directly to the properties of the SelectedTracking object.  These properties of the SelectedTracking object are iSource_Type and iDestination_Type.

Here is the column definition for iSourceType:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="SOURCE" SortMemberPath="tracking_source.chrSource" >
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FTC_DetailComboBox}"  Margin="0" Padding="3"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.TrackingSources, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                SelectedValuePath="idSource"
                DisplayMemberPath="chrSource"
                SelectedValue="{Binding iSource_Type, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

So when I assign these (iSource_Type, iDestination_Type) values in the ViewModel code (*in a selectionChanged function of the first "Action" comboBox*) the values are updated on the object itself.  But the change is not reflected back to the UI's comboboxes bound to these properties.

**What I tried:**

First:

I have an implementation of INotifyPropertyCHanged with a function called RaisePropertyChanged.  THis is provided through the MVVM_Light framework.  SO i tried to use the following:

```
RaisePropertyChanged("iDestination_Type")
RaisePropertyChanged("iSource_Type")
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTracking")
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTracking.iDestination_Type")
RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTracking.iSource_Type")
```

But these do not work.

Second:

I also tried to create properties in the viewmodel that bound to the SelectedTracking object.  But this just caused all the tracking objects to get the same values.

**Question:**
Can INotifyPropertyChanged work on properties that are not a part of the viewmodel, but are properties of objects found in the view model.  If so, what syntax do I need in the INotifyPropertyChanged event?

**Additional INformation:**
The MVVM-Light implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged (RaisePropertyChanged()) does not accept an empty string that would normaly update all UI elements.  So is there a way I can override the Implementation of INotifyPropertyCHanged in just one CLass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly you would like a way to notify your ViewModel of changes to your Model.

If so you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your model and subscribe to the model objects PropertyChanged event in your ViewModel. Here you can raise the property changed notification on your ViewModel properties.

A simple example to demonstrate the concept:

**Model:**

```
public class Tracking : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _isourcetype;
    private string _idestinationtype;

    public string SourceType
    {
        get { return _isourcetype; }
        set
        {
            _isourcetype = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SourceType");
        }
    }

    public string DestinationType
    {
        get { return _idestinationtype; }
        set
        {
            _idestinationtype = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("DestinationType");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class TrackingViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Tracking _selectedTracking;

    public string DestinationType
    {
        get { return _selectedTracking.DestinationType; }
    }

    public string SourceType
    {
        get { return _selectedTracking.SourceType; }
    }

    public Tracking SelectedTracking
    {
        get { return _selectedTracking; }
        set
        {
            _selectedTracking = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTracking");
        }
    }

    public TrackingViewModel()
    {
        _selectedTracking = new Tracking();
        _selectedTracking.PropertyChanged += SelectedTracking_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void SelectedTracking_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "SourceType":
                RaisePropertyChanged("SourceType");
                break;
            case "DestinationType":
                RaisePropertyChanged("DestinationType");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, my model already implemented iNotifyPropertyChanged, I wanted to keep the UI update calls all in my ViewModel out of principle (as the reason for the change of other comboboxes is business logic rather than data relationships), but its such a quick fix to add it to my model I will just go with it.